# How to customize logs exception in json format using log4j2.xml

Tags: json, logging, log4j2

I have tried writing my own pattern layout which writes my logs in json format but 50% exception are in json and 50% are not in json.
This logic should work for all exception, but I am not able to understand why this does not work for few cases.

Below is my patternlayout of log4j2.xml:

```
    <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
    <Console name="Console">
        <target>SYSTEM_OUT</target>
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="{&quot;timestamp&quot;:&quot;%d&quot;, &quot;docker_id&quot;:&quot;%X{DockerID}&quot;, &quot;app_name&quot;:&quot;${component_name}&quot;,&quot;app_version&quot;:&quot;${component_version}&quot;, &quot;request_id&quot;:&quot;%X{RequestID}&quot;, &quot;tenant&quot;:&quot;%X{Tenant}&quot;,&quot;log_level&quot;:&quot;%p&quot;, &quot;file&quot;:&quot;%C.%M&quot;,&quot;line&quot;:&quot;%L&quot;, &quot;message&quot;:&quot;%replace{%replace{%msg}{&quot;}{}}{[\r\n]+}{ }&quot;,&quot;exception&quot;:&quot;%enc{%rEx{full}}{JSON}&quot;%rEx{0}}%n" />
     </Console>
```

Could you please help me with this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly refrain from such a practice, given there is a superior alternative for that already: [JsonTemplateLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html)  shipped by Log4j 2.

The following template should do the job for you:

```json
{
  "timestamp": {
    "$resolver": "timestamp",
    "epoch": {
      "unit": "millis",
      "rounded": true
    }
  },
  "docker_id": {
    "$resolver": "mdc",
    "key": "DockerID"
  },
  "app_name": "${component_name}",
  "app_version": "${component_version}",
  "request_id": {
    "$resolver": "mdc",
    "key": "RequestID"
  },
  "tenant": {
    "$resolver": "mdc",
    "key": "Tenant"
  },
  "log_level": {
    "$resolver": "level",
    "field": "name"
  },
  "file": {
    "$resolver": "pattern",
    "pattern": "%C.%M",
    "stackTraceEnabled": false
  },
  "line": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "lineNumber"
  },
  "message": {
    "$resolver": "message",
    "stringified": true
  },
  "exception": {
    "$resolver": "exception",
    "field": "stackTrace",
    "stackTrace": {
      "stringified": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share me the customized log4j2.xml(just to show the example) which uses JsonTemplateLayout.  Because, I am getting issue while using JsonTemplateLayout.

Comment: @Sneha, I have edited the post. Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks @Volkan! But, I already tried doing the same and it did not work. Let me explain you what I did, Made one file with name "LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json" and placed that in the resources folder. The content of the file is exact same, what you suggested in previous post. Updated log4j2.xml with  <LogstashLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json"
                            prettyPrintEnabled="true"
                            stackTraceEnabled="true"/>   But didn work. Let me know where I am going wrong. After going through the Documentation I did this.

Comment: Tried with just: <LogstashLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json" />  and LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json file but, still no luck.

Comment: You should use `<JsonTemplateLayout`, not `<LogstashLayout`. Are you sure you have read the documentation I have linked?

Comment: Suggestion in the documentation: in combination with the log4j2.xml configuration use: <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json"/> and this is what I used. My previous comment had a copy paste issue(posted wrong info, please ignore that) . I have used this: <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json"/> but did not work. LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json file has content which is same as suggested by you in the 1st update. @Volkan Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Thanks its in json format now, I was making some mistake in log4j.xml by defining policies at wrong place. Now, I just need to configure how to printcustomized parameters like docker id, request id, tenant and line number. Because, I cannot see these fields in my log even after changing key to: "key": "%X{RequestID}" for request id, docker id and tenant id. For Line no I did %L but canoot see the value. @Volkan Thanks once again!

Comment: @Sneha, mind updating the question with _exactly_ what you are doing and what doesn't work, please? I have lost the track.

Comment: I'll summarize my query now: I am using <JsonTemplateLayout> and getting the logs in json format as expected. The only issue I am facing right now is, I dont know how to get the values of my custom fields in logs. My custom fields are DockerID, RequestId etc.. Now I am using like this in my template file:  "docker_id":"%X{DockerID}",
  "app_name": "${component_name}",
  "app_version": "${component_version}",
  "request_id": "%X{RequestId}",
  "tenant": "%X{TenantName}", I am getting correct value of app_name and version_name but not the rest of the custome fields.

Comment: I was getting these values correct when I was using pattern layout which I had posted in my 1st question.

Comment: I have already shared in my example for MDC fields you should use the following: `"tenant": { "$resolver": "mdc", "key": "TenantName" }`

Comment: Thank you so much Volkan for all your help. I am validating my changes now. Hope every exception gets captured properly in json format now.

Comment: Hi @Volkan, I have a query: If I do stacktrace in my code then those lines does not appear in json format in log. If I remove those stacktrace then it works fine. So, do we have any option to cater this? Even if I do stacktrace in my code but still log should appear in json?

Comment: @Sneha, I don't know what _do stacktrace in code_ means. Mind sharing a Gist/Paste of some sort reproducing the issue, please?

Comment: Hi @Volkan, Since we cannot do logger.info(e.printStackTrace()), this does not work,  So do we have any other way to send the stacktrace to logs? How can we get the stacktrace in logs?

Comment: @Sneha, Why not simply `logger.info("sharing the stack trace", e)`?

Comment: @VolkanYazıcı Is there a way to customize the `exception` resolver in JsonTemplate Layout like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67772434/how-to-customize-logs-exception-in-json-format-using-log4j2-xml) is asking?

Comment: @takanuva15, have you checked [the official documentation on `exception` resolver](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#event-template-resolver-exception)? If that doesn't work for you, could you please share your question in one of [the Log4j user support channels](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/support.html#discussions), please?